# Run two ApplicationReadyEvents one after another after application startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two classes that implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> as below. Since they both implement this interface they both run after startup but I  would like to always run ClassB after ClassA is run. I don't have control to modify ClassA. I can only make changes to classB. How can I make sure the ClassB always run after ClassA.

```
public class ClassA implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event){
        // do something
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassB implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `@Order` to `ClassB`. Ordered classes are invoked before unordered ones. Or let `ClassB` extend `ClassA`. Do your thing first in the `onApplicationEvent` and then call super.onApplicationEvent`. You have to make sure that there is just 1 listener (dependening on how they are registered that might not be possible).

Answer (score 0):

Just out of the blue I would try it with annotating each listener with `@Order`.
Spring normally orders injected lists this way. Could also be the case here.

Comment: It is working well for listeners, another option listeners can implement `org.springframework.core.Ordered` interface

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I mentioned I don’t have control to modify classA to add @Order. I can only make changes to classB

Answer (score 0):

In case when you really don't have a possibility to control one of the listeners and enforce its order via an annotation or implementing the `Ordered` interface, I don't see any other option than to do it directly in the application context's listener registry after the context is fully loaded. (Although I'd really suggest arranging it so that you do have control of how and when the `ClassA` listener is registered.)

Here's what you can do to guarantee your `ClassB` listener is registered after the `ClassA` one:

- make sure the `ClassB` listener you have control of is not a `@Component`, not declared as a `@Bean` and is not registered as a listener programmatically
- create a separate listener for the `ContextRefreshedEvent` that registers your `ClassB` listener:

```
    @Component
    public class ContextRefreshedEventListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
            final ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
            if (context instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
                final ConfigurableApplicationContext abstractApplicationContext = (AbstractApplicationContext) context;
                abstractApplicationContext.addApplicationListener(new ClassB());
            }
        }
    }
```